# Query number of users that like a page in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

If I put a facebook like button on a webpage, can I use FQL to query the number of users that 'liked' the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  Try the following FQL:

```
SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://your-web-page-url";
```

There's more stats available from the `link_stat` table as well.  The [table reference is here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/).